# PHP post calculation

Tags: php, mysql, forms

This is continuing off of [Multiple array insert into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523318/multiple-array-insert-into-database).

I've got everything setup but the calculation end of my tool. I'm a beginner PHP'er so bear with me.

I'm now trying to figure out how to multiply each items price thats pulled from the DB by the # that someone puts into the fields. Keeping in mind that not all fields will be filled out, so it will just have to ignore the ones left empty. It doesn't have to be a realtime calculation like javascript could achieve.Just once someone hits calculate, it echo's it out at the bottom. This is how I have my form currently setup.

```
<form name="ore_form" action="?page=ore" method='POST' class='oref'> 

    <input type=text name=veld><br>
    <input type=text name=scord><br> 
    <input type=text name=pyrox><br> 
    <input type=text name=plag><br> 
    <input type=text name=omber><br> 
    <input type=text name=kern><br> 
    <input type=text name=jasp><br> 
    <input type=text name=hemo><br>
    <input type=text name=hedb><br> 
    <input type=text name=Gneiss><br> 
    <input type=text name=dark><br> 
    <input type=text name=crok><br> 
    <input type=text name=spodu><br> 
    <input type=text name=bist><br> 
    <input type=text name=arko><br> 
    <input type=text name=merc><br> 
    <input type=submit value="Calculate">
```

I tried using after renaming each input name to 'veld'

```
$cut = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM data");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($cut))
 {

    echo $row['Price'] * .7 * $_POST['veld'];


 }
```

which partly worked but it just multiplied each box by that and didn't read the number I had or not multiply the ones left blank.

Comment: add some examples to your question, write what's the expected result and what's your actual result from your current code

Comment: you should at least do `intval($_POST['veld'])` or `floatval($_POST['veld'])`

Comment: Sorry for leaving that out - http://skiedude.com/dev/ore.php is where you can see my work in progress. The prices on the left are the current prices from my DB, the prices on the right are the prices * 70%. What should happen is the when someone puts 5 in the first 5 fields and hits calculate, it will then do 5*'each units price' and if the rest are left blank, don't do any caclulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to match the current row from your select to the appropriate input variable.  Looking at your other question, I see you use typeID as what I assume is your primary key.

With that in mind instead of naming your input "veld" I'd use the typeID as an array index

```
<input type=text name="product[p1230]" />
<input type=text name="product[p1228]" />
```

This way, all the inputs will be submitted as an array named 'product' in php.  Then you can use the rows typeID column to find the appropriate value in the product array.  I add the alpha character prefix 'p' to ensure an associative array is created and not a numerically indexed array, however, it probably would hurt nothing to use the numerical index typeID by itself.

```
$cut = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM data");
$prods = $_POST['product'];
$gtotal = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($cut)) {
  $price = $row['Price'] * .7 * $prods['p'.$row['typeID']]);
  $gtotal += $price;
  echo $price;
} 
echo $gtotal;
```

Comment: how would I get the grand total from all of this? to show at the bottom

Comment: You would need a separate variable in php that you would accumulate into within the while loop.

Comment: could you point me the right direction on setting that up? still going through each line of your while loop to understand it.

Comment: found the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329535/php-sum-variable-in-while-loop thanks to everyone for your help!

Comment: Just edited the original answer to illustrate for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here' an example:

```
if(isset($_POST['calculate'])){

$cut = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM data");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($cut))
 {

   if(empty($_POST['veld'])){

   $veldstorageprice=0;

   }
   else {

   $veldprice=$row['Price'];
   $veldstorageprice=$veldprice*.7;
   $veldstorageprice=$veldstorageprice*$_POST['veld']; /* Store the total price of Veldspar into this variable */
   echo "Price for Veldspar is ".$veldstorageprice."<br>";

   }

   if(empty($_POST['scord'])){

   $scordstorageprice=0;

   }
   else {

   $scordprice=$row['Price'];
   $scordstorageprice=$scordprice*.7;
   $scordstorageprice=$veldstorageprice*$_POST['scord']; /* Store the total price of Scordite into this variable */
   echo "Price for Scordite is ".$scordstorageprice."<br>";

   }    

   /* ALL YOU NEED TO DO IS COPY AND PASTE THIS CONDITION AND CHANGE THE POST VARIABLE TO THE CORRESPONDING ONE */

 } /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

/* After that loop, add all the stored variable prices */

$total=$veldstorageprice+$scordstorageprice;

echo "Total Price is ".$total;

}

<form name="ore_form" action="" method='POST' class='oref'> 

    <input type=number name=veld placeholder="Veldspar"><br>
    <input type=text name=scord placeholder="Scordite"><br>
    <input type=submit value="Calculate" name='calculate'>
    </form>
```

What I did is, the output will be above your textboxes, not in the bottom part. And I changed your input type *text* into *number*.

Here's a sample screen shot:
[image]

Comment: skiedude.com/dev/ore.php is where you can see my work in progress. The prices on the left are the current prices from my DB, the prices on the right are the prices * 70%. What should happen is the when someone puts 5 in the first 5 fields and hits calculate, it will then do 5*'each units price' and if the rest are left blank, don't do any calculations. The output will just echo # (they inputed into the box * .7 * current price (listed on left).

Comment: I still would like to keep the prices listed on the left so I would assume 2 different loops

Comment: After the result has been shown, what do you want to do with it? Do you want to insert it to your database?

Comment: No this is purely an information tool for a player to put in how much of each ore they want to sell, and then I'll have the total show up at the bottom of everything they put in they want to sell.

Comment: so desired outputs would be, next to each field it will show echo "price *.7 *# user inputed" showing the total for each item, then at the bottom it will show the grand total

Comment: never mind its changed since last refreshing, trying new code

Comment: Is your $row['Price'] all the same?

Comment: I've tried doing it in my local computer, and it works. Though I'm not using prices from your database.

Comment: I forgot '.' It should be echo "Price for Scordite is ".$scordstorageprice."<br>"; Not echo "Price for Scordite is "$scordstorageprice"<br>";

Comment: Please see updated answer. And still do the rest to the other fields.

Comment: I did take your suggestion on changing the inputs to numbers, good catch on that. For the sake of my newb eyes getting lost in code, I'm leaning towards the 2nd answer that does a while loop through all the typeIDs. I do appreciate you taking this in the right direction and taking the time to help me out :). My next task is working with sessions so the fields stay populated after they submit but I'll dink around with that on my own :)